# Is it possible to rollback only one command (not whole transaction) in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, rollback, savepoints

I know that you do the BEGIN; command, then all commands after that can be rolled back, as long as you haven't executed COMMIT; yet. My question is, is there a command to roll back just one command and not ALL commands after the BEGIN? I'm using Postgres by the way.

Answer (score 2):

Read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/tutorial-transactions.html about `SAVEPOINT` and `ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT`.

Comment: Note that each savepoint consumes some resources so don't just blindly issue one before every statement in a framework or anything like that.

Comment: Having to create a savepoint manually for each transaction seems like a tedious process. I'm guessing there's no command that undos the transactions one by one like ctrl+z without having to create a savepoint for each rollback

Comment: No, there is not. Suppose you wanted to rollback a transaction in which you did DELETE of a million rows. The database would have to secretly store those data indefinitely, just in case you might want to Ctrl-Z the DELETE someday.

Comment: There is some discussion of adding a feature for _temporal tables_ to PostgreSQL in some future version. A code patch exists, but it is not committed. See https://blog.dbi-services.com/temporal-tables-for-postgresql-15/